# How to control SlidingMenu in the method of onKeyDown

Tags: android, onkeydown, slidingmenu

I want to achieve the function that when I click "back" button on phone,the menu will show.And then I write the code below:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) &&(event.getRepeatCount() == 0)) {
            if(!getSlidingMenu().isMenuShowing()){
                toggle();
                //getSlidingMenu().showMenu();
            }
```

But the in fact,if the "getSlidingMenu().isMenuShowing()==true" the menu will be dismiss.And if(!getSlidingMenu().isMenuShowing()),the menu will come up with only a short time and then dismiss automatic.And what I want is the menu is just showing.

Comment: Firstly override onBackPressed is better than using onKeyDown to capture Back button click event.
Secondly you should provide your code for the isMenuShowing method where you said the problem is.

Comment: isMenuShowing is the method which jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu provides.It returns the boolean of the state of wheather slidingmenu is shown.

Answer (score 0):

onBackPressed is invoked when the 'back' button in Android device is pressed.

Hence, you need to override the onBackPressed as mentioned previously. Your logic is partially correct, but it has to be inside onBackPressed

The following code Snippet should work (if I understand your problem correctly):

```
public void onBackPressed() 
{   
    if (!getSlidingMenu().isMenuShowing()) {
        super.toggle();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed(); // invoke super's method or other logic?
    }

}
```

Here's the documentation from Android onBackPressed() - Added in API level 5

```
Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back key. The 
default implementation simply finishes the current activity, but you can override 
this to do whatever you want.
```